# arcpy.Erase_analysis function and output

Tags: arcpy

I have attached my code (Python). I am trying to loop trough each FC in same file GDB and subtract a FC from remaining FCs not equal to input FC. Then want to create/generate FC from erased result function. Also, I want to give specific FC name to the output. I can get to the end of my script, except last line.

Example: GDB has [A,B,C,D] - 4 FCs.
1st round:
input FC: A     (Do not use A-A)
Output should be A-B and called Product_By_AB
       should be A-C and called Product_By_AC
       should be A-D and called Product_By_AD
2nd round:
input FC:B (Do not use B-B)
Output should be B-A and called Product_By_BA
       should be B-C and called Product_By_BC
       should be B-D and called Product_By_BD
and so on.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\input.gdb'

Match_FC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fclass in Match_FC:
  for fc in Match_FC:
    if fc != fclass:
        fclass_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fclass, "fclass_lyr")
        fc_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "fc_lyr")
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fclass_lyr, 'INTERSECT', fc_lyr)
        desc = arcpy.Describe("fclass_lyr")
        fcIntersect=[]
        if desc.FIDSet:

             output='{}'.format(fclass)

            arcpy.Erase_analysis(fclass, fc,output, '')


        else:
           arcpy.Delete_management(fclass_lyr)
        arcpy.Delete_management(fc_lyr)

    else:
        "Skipping FC-{}".format(fc)
```

Comment: Your indenting is inconsistent. You need to format your code properly to follow the looping. As it stands your code is unreadable. Do you have any specific error mesage? I don't understand why Matched=fclass[len(fclass)-20:] .. surely that doesn't exist in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, the following modification to your code should do the trick.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\input.gdb'

Match_FC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fclass in Match_FC: # Loop through the feature classes you want to erase from
    print "Feature Class = {}".format(fclass)
    for fc in Match_FC: # Loop through the erasing feature classes
        if fc != fclass: # If they aren't the same feature class
            print "Erase Feature Class = {}".format(fc)
            output = r'C:\output.gdb\Product_by_{}{}'.format(fclass, fc) # Name the output feature class
            arcpy.Erase_analysis(fclass, fc, output, '') # Erase the features and store in the output
        else: # If they are they same feature class, then skip
            print "Skipping matching Feature Class {}".format(fc)
```

Basically it

1. loops through all your feature classes to erase from,
2. then inside that loop it loops through the same FCs to find the FCs to use to erase.
3. If they're not the same FC then perform the erase into a new output FC (using the naming convention you specified),
4. or if they are they same FC then skip it.

You don't need to use Feature Class to Feature Class as the `Erase` tool already outputs to a new feature class for you.

---

To check for overlap and skip if no overlap, try this:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\input.gdb'

Match_FC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fclass in Match_FC:
    print "Feature Class = {}".format(fclass)
    for fc in Match_FC:
        if fc != fclass:
            print "Erase Feature Class = {}".format(fc)

            fclass_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fclass, "fclass_lyr")
            fc_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "fc_lyr")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fclass_lyr, 'INTERSECT', fc_lyr)
            desc = arcpy.Describe("fclass_lyr")
            if desc.FIDSet:
                output = r'C:\output.gdb\Product_by_{}{}'.format(fclass, fc)
                arcpy.Erase_analysis(fclass, fc, output, '')
            else:
                print "Skipping - No Features Overlap"
            arcpy.Delete_management(fclass_lyr)
            arcpy.Delete_management(fc_lyr)

        else:
            print "Skipping matching Feature Class {}".format(fc)
```

Comment: Could you help me how can I add condition and lets tool check before executing Erase function check for if my polygons are overlapped or no, then execute the erase for just overlaps FC.

Comment: adding a `Select Features By Location` before your erase, and then check for selected features.  If nothing selected then don't erase, if something is selected then clear the selection and do the erase.  I'll try to update my answer to include

Comment: Should I put after:  if fc != fclass: # and indent inside or no!

Comment: yes inside the `if fc != fclass: `, so indented.  Should be `Select Layer by Location` (not Feature like I said in my earlier comment).  You'll need to `Make Feature Layer`